# Create a dictionary from an XML using xpath

Tags: python, xml, dictionary, xpath

I would like to create a dictionary from an XML file unsing xpath. Here's an example of the XML:

```
</Contract>
    <Contract ID="1">
      <UnwantedPatterns>
        <Pattern>0</Pattern>
        <Pattern>1</Pattern>
 </Contract>
    <Contract ID="2
      <UnwantedPatterns>
        <Pattern>0</Pattern>
        <Pattern>1</Pattern>
 </Contract>
```

What I would like it's having the contract ID as key and the unwanted patterns as value.
Here's my code:

```
UnwantedPatterns = []
key = []
DictUP = {}

for ID in root.xpath('//Contracts'):
    key = ID.xpath('./Contract/@ID')
    for patterns in root.xpath('.//Contract/UnwantedPatterns/Pattern'):
        DictUP[key] = UnwantedPatterns.append(patterns.text)
```

I get the error "unhashable type: 'list'". Thank you for your help, the output should look like that:

{1: 0,1

2: 0,1}

Comment: Your expected output is not supported syntax. Did you mean `{1: (0, 1), 2: (0,1)}`?

Comment: Hello, Donny yes that what I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`xpath` returns `list`, so instead of

```
key = ID.xpath('./Contract/@ID')
```

try

```
key = ID.xpath('./Contract/@ID')[0]
```

As for output, as dictionary cannot have multiple values with the same key  `DictUP[key] = UnwantedPatterns.append(patterns.text)` will overwrite value on each iteration.

Try

```
for ID in root.xpath('//Contracts'):
    key = ID.xpath('./Contract/@ID')[0]
    _patterns = []
    for unwanted in root.xpath('.//Contract/UnwantedPatterns'):
        _patterns.extend([pattern.text for pattern in unwanted.xpath('./Pattern')])
    DictUP[key] = _patterns
```

Comment: Thank for your answer, I tried the code but unfortunatelly it doesn't give me the expected output. Instead of {1: (0, 1), 2: (0,1)} I get: {0:(0,1,0,1)}. I tried different variation of the code but I'm still stuck.